# Error parsing Gemfile for Jekyll theme: unexpected unary-, expecting keyword_do

Tags: ruby, rubygems, themes, jekyll

[I am trying to create a gem theme for jekyll but I keep getting an error every time I run bundle install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRxCP.png)

[Here is the error: unexepected unary-, expecting keyword_do, or '{' or "('-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNsq4.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add both the code and the complete error message into the text field. Screen shots of code are not very helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814140/jekyll-custom-theme-gemspec-bundle-install-error-unexpected-unary-expecting

Comment: here's a better version of the question! sorry I'm new to this